# Robot Framework - Getting a Text of a Div with no ID

Tags: selenium, variables, testing, xpath, robotframework

I am using robot framework,

I have to verify, that a users name is the same on one page and other page,

There are multiple different users, I need to get the Text of the `div` the users.

Right now the name is hard coded but when the user dissapears after being assign to something, the test will fail although everything is working,

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${User_Div} =  //*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]
${User_Name} =  John Doe


*** Keywords ***
//..more code here irelevant..//
Validate User Name
    Click Element  ${Resident_Div}
    page should contain  ${Resident_Name}
```

This is the value of the div

```
<span><!-- react-text: 116 -->John<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 117 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 118 -->Doe<!-- /react-text --></span>
```

What I am trying to do is Get the text of `${User_Div}` on load of the div and store it in this variable, to verify the next page contains the same page.

> Note: The web app is designed with react, there is ID on the div.

Update:

I will try to make it clearer here

```
Look for ${User_Div}
Get Text value of ${User_Div}
Assign text value of ${User_Div} to ${User_Name}
the outcome should be ${User_Name} == ${User_Div} text
```

Comment: By value you mean text?

Comment: @JaPyR yes my bad I changed it to text

Comment: Could you provide more details? I am not sure what's the problem and what kind of help do you need.

Comment: @JaPyR Ive updated my answer hopefully it makes more sens

Comment: I can say for sure that you should not use such xpath, it's very fragile and change to application (or even during refresh) will result in error.

Comment: Could you please provide a relevant `HTML` code block of your element(not just one row)? Than we can assemble `xPath` to this element.

Comment: You should work with your developers to add a unique id or class to the element so that you can easily reference it in your tests.